# how to draw a scatterdiagram of two sets of strings in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, plot, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I want to draw a scatter diagram between two array of strings. On calling scatter() I'm getting the following error.

return amin(axis, out)

TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type

Comment: please post your code :)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by: "drawing a scatter diagram between two array of strings".

This command generates the error you said, but it has no meaning:

```
plt.scatter('azerty','qsdfgh')
```

Comment: I've two arrays of name. say, A = ['test1','test2'] and B = ['test3','test4']. I want to draw a scatter plot where my X axis will be elements of A, Y axis will be element of B and if there exists any correlation between element of A and element of B, it'll be shown in the scattered plot. how to do that?

Comment: I am still not sure to understand what you want to do. scatter plot, like plot, take numeric values as input, not string. So, first, if you want to compare strings, you should decide what kind of metric/correlation function to use and apply it to your data.

Comment: See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metric) for example of string metrics and choose which correspond best to your problem